# Angular JS ionic search box with clear field button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My app is using ionic and angular js.. I am trying to add a clear button for the search, but Its not working?.. my Code is:

HTML:

```
  <div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>
    <button class="button ion-android-close input-button button-small"
              ng-click="clearSearch()" ng-if="search.length">
            </button>

  </div>
```

APP.JS

```
  $scope.clearSearch = function() {
   $scope.search = '';
 };
```

Maybe i need something more but this is not working?

Any help thanks?

Comment: It looks straight forward, can clear your cache and test again?  Still you able to get the issue, then problem with your other parts of the code. If possible, provide some more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with ng-if use ng-show instead.

```
<div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>

    <button ng-click="search = ''" class="button ion-android-close input-button button-small" ng-show="search.length">Clear
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. How would you modify this to use clear buttons and inputs? like the default look for input fields and clear buttons, how do i lose the inset look?

Comment: I do not understand why this is not working for me `<a ng-show="search.length" ng-click="search=''"><i class="icon ion-close placeholder-icon"></i></a>`

Answer (score 3):

> To use a button along the input, swap the label to a span or div, your
>   ng-clicks will work fine after that.